# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 when migrating from jcenter to mavenCentral

Tags: android, gradle, jcenter, maven-central

Jfrog is going to shutdown jcenter and that means we cannot use jcenter in our build.gradle file for downloading needed libraries and as i saw in different websites and also in [android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration) we can use mavenCentral() instead of jcenter but when is replace it with jcenter and rebuild the project i get following error that means `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0` specified in project level build.gradle file is not exist in `mavenCentral()` and `google()` repositories.

[image]
and when i click on that links i get 404 error
this is my project level build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
  buildscript {
    repositories {
      google()
      mavenCentral()
    }
  dependencies {
       classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"

       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
     google()
     mavenCentral()
  }
}

  task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this Problem  with Jcenter too
Check your vpn and change the conection type of vpn.